# Having regex issue across multiple lines

Tags: javascript, html, regex, google-apps-script

I am using Google Apps Script to look for order confirmation emails (like from Amazon and Target) and extract the total price for the order.

An email from target includes multiple Dollar values (individual items, taxes, and the total). I thought I could identify the total price by looking for the word "total" and then getting whatever the next $ value is.

Here is an excerpt of the email body.

```
                   <table  cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" border=3D"0=
">
                        <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <span style=3D"font-family:Arial, Hel=
vetica, sans-serif;font-size:18px;color:#231f20;font-weight:bold;">total:</=
span>
                                    </td>                                  =
=20
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td align=3D"right">
                    <table  cellspacing=3D"0" cellpadding=3D"0" border=3D"0=
">
                        <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                      <span style=3D"font-family:Arial, Hel=
vetica, sans-serif;font-size:18px;font-weight:bold;color:#231f20">$26.49</s=
pan>
                                    </td>                                  =
=20
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                   =20
</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
```

This is the regex I built and tested

```
/total:(?:.*\n)*.*\$\d+\.\d{2}/
```

It works on a text site, such as https://regexr.com/.

However, in my script it doesn't work. Using the debugger, I can see that my variable never gets filled with the match. However, it does work if I dumb down the regex to

```
/total:/
```

Here is my code:

```
function testGmail() {
  var threads = GmailApp.getInboxThreads();
  var messages = GmailApp.getMessagesForThreads(threads)
  
  for (var i = 0 ; i < threads.length; i++) {
    var from = messages[i][0].getFrom()
    switch(from) {
      case "\"Amazon.com\" <no-reply@amazon.com>":
        Logger.log("From is Amazon")
        break
        
      case "\"Target.com\" <orders@service.target.com>":
        Logger.log("From is Target")
        
        var body = messages[i][0].getRawContent()
        var amount = parseMessageData(body)
        Logger.log(amount)
        
        break
        
        default:
        Logger.log("From is " + from)
    }
    
  }
}

function parseMessageData(body) {
  
  // Look for the price
  var regExAmount = /total:/
  var amountmatch = body.match(regExAmount)
  var amount = amountmatch[0].replace(/[^\d.]/g, '') // only keeps digits and periods (.) (to remove $ sign and any commas)
  
  return amount
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with this:

```
/total:[\s\S]*?\$(\d+\.\d{2})/
```

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Your are not getting the *next* amount after “total”, but the *last* amount after “total”, because of your `*` quantifier, which is *greedy*.

The total amount is captured in group 1 of:

```
[Tt]otal[\s\S]*?\$([\d.]+)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/2vwfdM4YdkqtrO).

The trick is using `[\s\S]` to match anything including newlines, and adding `?` after `*` to make the quantifier *reluctant* - stopping at the *next* “$”.

Comment: It seems that (?i) does not work for Javascript regex, which is presumably what Google Apps Script uses...I will attempt to dissect what you've provided and see if I can create something similar.

Comment: @matt just remove `(?i)` then. It makes the match case insensitive, but there are other ways: See edited answer.